# How to pause task to complete another task

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

I currently have 2 identical projects beginning at different times (will be adding more).

The manager has a number of "Review" tasks spread out in the project as well as some of his own work. The Reviews take priority over his own work and I don't mind delays to his work because of this.

How can I have a resource pause their current task, carry out another task and then go back to their previous task once complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Start with a well developed, logic driven schedule network.
2. Assign the manager as a resource to the required tasks.
3. Assign the "Review" tasks a higher priority than other competing tasks.
4. In leveling options, select Leveling order: Priority, Standard.
5. Check "Leveling can create splits in remaining work."
6. Execute "Level Resource."
7. Done.